# Making subclass more type-specific with accessors

Tags: java, design, programming-practices, polymorphism

I have a super class: `TriggerManager` with a subclass `TimedTriggerManager`. NOTE: I'm working in java

`TimedTriggerManager` only deals with `TimedTrigger` s, a subclass of `Trigger`. `TriggerManager` references all `Trigger` objects. To modify the subclass (`TimedTriggerManager`) to only accept `TimedTriggers` into its accessors and mutators (getters and setters) I have the following questions:

1) I have in `TriggerManager` the following `public void addTrigger(Trigger t)`. In `TimedTriggerManager` should I just override the method to throw an error if the argument (`t`) is not a `TimedTrigger`. If so, What error should I throw? If not, what should I do?

2) Should I add another method `getTimedTrigger` to work alongside the supper class's `getTrigger` so that I don't have to keep type casting? (Since the latter would return a `Trigger` object)

3) Is there anything else I'm forgetting, or some common practice that I'm not doing?

Comment: see also: [Template pattern with varying input type in overridden method](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/267038/31260)

Answer (score 4):

Your situation reeks of the classic Shape hierarchy where a Square inherits from Rectangle (and adds the constraint that both dimensions are the same). This is generally regarded as failing the [Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), because the added constraint makes that the base-class operations are not always appropriate for the derived class.

If the `getTrigger` method is only meant for use within the hierarchy, then you could turn the inheritance between `TriggerManager` and `TimedTriggerManager` around (making `TimedTriggerManager` the base class), as a derived class may weaken the requirements placed on method parameters but not strengthen them.

If `getTrigger` is also meant for outside use, then `TriggerManager` and `TimedTriggerManager` can't have an inheritance relation with each other without violating the LSP.
In that case, it might be best to make `TriggerManager` and `TimedTriggerManager` sibling-classes that both inherit from a `AbstractTriggerManager`. The `AbstractTriggerManager` provides all the common functionality, but no public methods where `TriggerManager` and `TimedTriggerManager` place different requirements on the parameters (such as `addTrigger`).

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes. Unless you have a common interface for both `Trigger` and `TimedTrigger`, which means the `TimedTriggerManager` does not require any special functionality from `TimedTrigger`, you should check the type of the received `Trigger` and ensure its a `TimedTrigger`.

2) It doesn't seem a good idea to me. The base class usually should not know anything about the the derived classes. So I think casting is not a big problem here. It results in a cleaner design in my opinion.

3) Do you actually use a concrete `TriggerManager` class directly? One think that you may want to consider is to use an interface instead of a base object for the specialized managers.